# Page not found (404) Request Method: GET ....... the current path, blog/blogpost, didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django, web, model, blogs

Hi i am trying to make blog website but while i fetch model with blogpost function in views.py its shows error that 404 page not found like  *||Using the URLconf defined in mac.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:      admin/     shop/     blog/ [name='BlogHome']     blog The current path, blog/blogpost, didn't match any of these. ||*

-until i don't create model it works fine but after creating model and trying to fetch articles through post_id  it throws error as page not found!
-what am i missing?
-Here is the codes i am using.

code of blog/urls.py ->

```
    from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(" ", views.index, name="ShopHome"),
    path("blogpost/<int:id>/", views.blogpost, name="blogpost")]
```

code of blog/Views.py ->

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Blog

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
        return render(request, 'blog/index.html')

def blogpost(request,id):
    post= Blog.objects.filter (post_id=id)[0] 
    print(post)
    return render(request, 'blog/blogpost.html',{'post':post})
```

code of blog/adminpy ->

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Blog


admin.site.register(Blog)
```

code of blog/models.py ->

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Blog(models.Model):
    post_id = models.AutoField(primary_key= True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    title0 = models.CharField(max_length=500,default='')
    title1= models.CharField(max_length=500,default='')
    title2= models.CharField(max_length=500,default='')
    Content_title= models.CharField(max_length=500,default='')
    Content_title0= models.CharField(max_length=500,default='')
    Content_title1= models.CharField(max_length=500,default='')
    Content_title2= models.CharField(max_length=500,default='')
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='shop/images', default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Please post actual code not screenshots of code

Comment: included ' / ' into urls but that didn't worked getting the same error log/ blogpost/<int:id>/ [name='blogpost']  The current path, blog/blogpost/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: because you actually have to add a pk of an existing blogpost instance in your url, check out my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an `/<int:id>/` (btw always include the last trailing slash in your urls `/`) but your path says **/blog/blogpost** with a *str* parameter where it should be an *int* representing the `id` of an *existing* `Blogpost` instance.